Integrate Google Tasks into Android application
I spent last 2 days reading, and I am more confused than ever. There seems to be almost no documentation except these 2 links:

Google Tasks REST API, however it only contains examples for Java (desktop), Python, and PHP. Nothing related to Android whatsoever

Tasks API on Android which is deprecated


I've tried to search stackoverflow posts, but almost all links from similar answers are broken or missing. A lot seems to have changed in the past decade.
I could also find these projects on github, which seems to be maintained:

Google APIs Client Library for Java
Google Java API Client Services

But then again, no explanation of their context or usage on Android.
Surely there must be some kind of a documentation or tutorial, can anybody point me in the right direction please? Thanks!
